# Take 2 columns in file and replace it recursively

Tags: shell, awk, scripting

I have n files stores as .dat in a directory, I need to take only the fist two columns in each one and remove the original.

I did it for a single file

```
awk '{print $1,$2}' Test.dat > Test.dat.col
rm Test.dat
rename 's/.dat.col/.dat/' Test.dat.col
```

How can I do it recursive?

My failed attempt for the first part `find *.dat -printf "awk '{print $1,$2}' > \"%f.col\" | sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you have GNU `awk` recent version, you could simply do.

```
awk -i inplace '{print $1,$2}' *.dat
```

***Generic solution:*** In case you don't have recent version of GNU `awk` could you please try following then.

```
awk -v temp="temp" '
FNR==1{
  if(file){
     close(temp)
     system("mv \047" temp "\047 \047" file "\047")
  }
  file=FILENAME
}
{
  print $1,$2 > (temp)
}
' *.dat
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not have the recent version but after `sudo apt install gawk` and check the version (4.1.4) `awk -W version` it worked just fine.

Comment: @NicolasG, Np, please check my updated solution. I added a generic solution and tested it, it looks fine to me, please lemme know if that helps you?

Comment: No, the Generic solution throws the following error `sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`. I Don't see where they are missing...

Comment: @NicolasG,not sure it worked fine for me, in my code just make a small change edit `temp` to `(temp)` once and try same code with new change once if that helps you?

Comment: @NicolasG, BTW, just for cinfirmation purposes, after GNU awk installation,my gawk solution worked fine for you correct?

Comment: @NicolasG, Glad that it helped you. You mean both right(for me both of them worked) just need your confirmation so that it can help future users.